# Is there a way to enable trace to display the sequence of decisions executed for a DMN in Kogito?

Tags: quarkus, dmn, kogito

I finally got my sample dmn-quarkus example running. Is there a property that enables the trace, such a way it prints the sequence of decisions executed?

I noticed that when I provide a incorrect JSON for my DMN model, Kogito responds with a detail response, telling me which decision failed.

This is awesome! Is there a property to turn on to get the details in each response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kogito is based on a domain-model first approach to code generation

> **Kogito ergo domain**
>
> Kogito adopts to your business domain rather than the other way around [...]

this means the automatically code-generated API will always take the "shape" of the input/output context of the DMN model, and no longer the v7.x kie-server approach of a generic API.

The information you obtain during error is meant to provide an analogous to a stacktrace.

You can always leverage the Kogito API programming model to build the REST service yourself, in the way better fit your specific business requirement --shall that be provide a list of `DMNDecisionResult(s)`. For instance a pragmatic approach could be to inspect the automatically generated code, and then code a bespoke service, based on this one.

We are looking into **Audit functional requirements**, but that is not provided out of the box yet. We always welcome community feedback, especially even more in this very early versions! Don't hesitate to join the [community](https://kogito.kie.org/community/) on our [mailing-list](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/kogito-development) or raise a [JIRA ticket](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/KOGITO) to take part of the conversation, the team will be glad to look further into it considering community feedback and suggestions!