# How to return decision results while executing DMN model

Tags: drools, quarkus, dmn, kogito

I am perusing Kogito for our project and I am building a prototype. What I notice, is when the input json doen't doesn't meet the interface contract to make a decision, kogito responses with error details. It also provides decision execution details.

Is there a way to turn on the decision results in the response as we need it for audit purposes.

Need this trace for each response

```
"decision-results": [
        {
            "decision-id": "_260E6369-DE61-464C-889B-04B24776D47E",
            "decision-name": "A",
            "result": 200,
            "messages": [],
            "status": "SUCCEEDED"
        },
        {
            "decision-id": "_1728962B-CF7A-4EEF-9AFB-50C961A3AB0B",
            "decision-name": "D",
            "result": null,
            "messages": [
                {
                    "level": "ERROR",
                    "dmn-message-severity": "ERROR",
                    "message": "Unable to evaluate decision 'D' as it depends on decision 'C'",
                    "message-type": "REQ_NOT_FOUND",
                    "source-id": "_1728962B-CF7A-4EEF-9AFB-50C961A3AB0B"
                }
            ],
            "status": "SKIPPED"
        },
        {
            "decision-id": "_433DCDBB-3674-4EF9-96BC-B766B9CB54EC",
            "decision-name": "C",
            "result": null,
            "messages": [
                {
                    "level": "ERROR",
                    "dmn-message-severity": "ERROR",
                    "message": "Required dependency 'Subject Loan' not found on node 'C'",
                    "message-type": "REQ_NOT_FOUND",
                    "source-id": "_433DCDBB-3674-4EF9-96BC-B766B9CB54EC"
                }
            ],
            "status": "SKIPPED"
        },
        {
            "decision-id": "_8468FF9C-1DE1-4E93-9828-088F7690B18F",
            "decision-name": "B",
            "result": 3220,
            "messages": [],
            "status": "SUCCEEDED"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to enable trace to display the sequence of decisions executed for a DMN in Kogito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60453840/is-there-a-way-to-enable-trace-to-display-the-sequence-of-decisions-executed-for)